# What is the undefined local variable or method in Installing Homebrew for Mac?

Tags: python, macos, installation, pygame, homebrew

My end goal is to install Pygame into my personal mac, so I'm following the instructions of how as provided by this website: http://brysonpayne.com/2015/01/10/setting-up-pygame-on-a-mac/
. I copy and pasted the command necessary to download Homebrew as provided at Step 4 on the website:

> 4. Install Homebrew: At the Terminal command line prompt, type the following as a single full line (you may want to expand your Terminal window wider to allow it to fit, but it’s okay if it wraps around):
>      ruby -e “$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)”
>      then, hit return.

But my terminal states that the command is undefined. What should I attempt to do next to reach my end goal?

I installed xcode and xquartz softwares as suggested and tried copying and pasting the command.

```
$ ruby -e “$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)”
```

```
-e:1:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `“' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Comment: That website has has unhelpfully changed `"` (normal double quotes) to  `“` + `”` "Smart-quotes" on the command. That's what's in the pasted `ruby` command above.  Have you tried replacing the  `“` + `”` with `"` in the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author wrong typed `"` as `“`. The two quote symbols are different.

Use the installation script from [Homebrew official website](https://brew.sh/).

```sh
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```